# How to convert t-sql datefromparts in Databricks sparkSQL without creating a function

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks-sql

I have the following T-SQL code that I would like to convert to sparkSQL

```
SELECT datefromparts(YEAR(sysdatetime()) - 1, 12, 31)
```

The problem is there isn't an equivalent 'datefromparts' function in sparkSQL.

Can someone show me how to convert the T-SQL to sparkSQL

The output should be 31/12/2022

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `trunc` function for this case.

```
select trunc(current_date(),'year')-1 as req_dt
#req_dt
#2022-12-31
```

---

To format date use `date_format` function

```
select date_format(trunc(current_date(),'year')-1,'MM/dd/yyyy') as req_dt

#req_dt
#12/31/2022
```